# Build on shell condition with Make

Tags: linux, makefile

I would like to add to a build list the packages I want to build if it is not installed yet.

The goal is to install some Python packages without pip and from local sources. I don't have access to pip...

So I wrote I Makefile that looks like:

```
all: natsort foo bar foobar ...

natsort: natsort-4.0.4.tar.gz
    tar xvzf $<
    cd $(patsubst %.tar.gz,%, $<) && python setup.py install
    rm -rf $(patsubst %.tar.gz,%, $<)
    python -c 'import natsort'
    echo -e "Installation of $< [done]\n" >> install.log
```

The problem with this implementation is that all the packages will be rebuild and reinstalled each time I run the Make command. I would like to check if the module is already installed. My idea is to do something like this:

```
ifdef $(shell python -c 'import natsort')
all: natsort
endif
```

How can I rewrite this to make it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can absolutely do something like that. But it "costs" a shell invocation and an invocation of python every time you run `make` and that's a relatively high cost.

There are, basically, two ways to do what you want in a cheaper manner.

A stamp file and short-circuiting logic in the recipe.

The stamp file method is basically what you have except you add `touch $@` to the end of the recipe.

```
natsort: natsort-4.0.4.tar.gz
    tar xvzf $<
    cd $(patsubst %.tar.gz,%, $<) && python setup.py install
    rm -rf $(patsubst %.tar.gz,%, $<)
    python -c 'import natsort'
    echo -e "Installation of $< [done]\n" >> install.log 
    touch $@
```

That way running the recipe the first time creates the stamp file and until `natsort-4.0.4.tar.gz` becomes newer than the stamp file or the stamp file gets deleted the recipe will never run again.

Note that second point though. Delete the stamp file and you install again.

That's the thing that the short-circuit logic solution solves.

Instead of your original rule of multiple commands you wrap it all in one command (this is optional but saves repeated checking costs) and check for the module to be installed before doing any work.

```
natsort: natsort-4.0.4.tar.gz
    if ! python -c 'import natsort'; then \
        tar xvzf $< || exit 1; \
        cd $(patsubst %.tar.gz,%, $<) && python setup.py install || exit 1; \
        rm -rf $(patsubst %.tar.gz,%, $<); \
        python -c 'import natsort' || exit 1; \
        echo -e "Installation of $< [done]\n" >> install.log; \
    fi
```

Note the need to add `|| exit 1` since we no longer have make handling that for us. Also note that this now *always* runs the rule (and we should mark `natsort` and `.PHONY`) but in the most common case it will stop after the `if` test.

That all said you can combine these methods to get the best of both worlds.

```
natsort: natsort-4.0.4.tar.gz
    if ! python -c 'import natsort'; then \
        tar xvzf $< || exit 1; \
        cd $(patsubst %.tar.gz,%, $<) && python setup.py install || exit 1; \
        rm -rf $(patsubst %.tar.gz,%, $<); \
        python -c 'import natsort' || exit 1; \
        echo -e "Installation of $< [done]\n" >> install.log; \
    fi
    touch $@
```

and you get the benefits of both methods. The first time you run `make` the `natsort` file doesn't exist and the recipe is run. `natsort` isn't installed so the `if` test fails and the installation occurs. After that the `natsort` file it `touch`ed. The next time make is installed `natsort` is newer than `natsort-4.0.4.tar.gz` so `make` doesn't think it has anything to do. If, for some reason, you delete the `natsort` file then the next time `make` runs it checks for the module to exist, skips the installation and `touch`es the `natsort` file again to get back into sync.